# Connect power Bi to multiple data sources

Tags: powerbi

I am using SQL with several databases and I would like to have separate dashboards for each database. However, I am not getting a way to configure power Bi gateway to connect to different databases. Is there an option for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort the issue. You just need to click "ADD DATA SOURCE"